# MVC Update Details Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this Truck Maintenance Scheduling System, now this is my Update Truck Details Controller, in updating this I have to also update the truck's current run, and the truck current run will go to the last run? I'm having a hard time to figure it out. This is my code:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateTruck(TruckDetails u, int id)
    {

        var updateTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

        if (updateTruck == null)
            return View(u);

        var lastrun = db.trucks.Select( s => s.current_run); // This is my problem, getting the current run value from the database

        updateTruck.registration_no = u.reg_no;
        updateTruck.make = u.make;
        updateTruck.model = u.model;
        updateTruck.engine_no = u.engine_no;
        updateTruck.chassis_no = u.chassis_no;
        updateTruck.driver_name = u.driver_name;
        updateTruck.driver_no = u.driver_no;
        updateTruck.is_updated = DateTime.Now;
        updateTruck.current_run = u.current_run;
        updateTruck.last_run = lastrun; 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(u);
        }

        return View(u);


    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have no idea what advice you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set lastrun = updateTruck.current_run after you get the entity from the database

```
public ActionResult UpdateTruck(TruckDetails u, int id) {

    var updateTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id);

    if (updateTruck == null)
        return View(u);

    var lastrun = updateTruck.current_run;

    updateTruck.registration_no = u.reg_no;
    updateTruck.make = u.make;
    updateTruck.model = u.model;
    updateTruck.engine_no = u.engine_no;
    updateTruck.chassis_no = u.chassis_no;
    updateTruck.driver_name = u.driver_name;
    updateTruck.driver_no = u.driver_no;
    updateTruck.is_updated = DateTime.Now;
    updateTruck.current_run = u.current_run;
    updateTruck.last_run = lastrun; 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(u);
    }

    return View(u);


}
```

**FWIW** I'd probably clean up the code a little bit.  You were accepting a parameter of `int id` in you action but never passing it back to the view if there was an issue, so I'm assuming the id should probably be on your TruckDetails model, so you should probably use that, or add it there.  You also want to skip all that other code if your ModelState is invalid

```
    public ActionResult UpdateTruck(TruckDetails u)
    {
        if (u != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var updateTruck = db.trucks.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == u.id);
            if (updateTruck != null)
            {
                var lastrun = updateTruck.current_run;
                updateTruck.registration_no = u.reg_no;
                updateTruck.make = u.make;
                updateTruck.model = u.model;
                updateTruck.engine_no = u.engine_no;
                updateTruck.chassis_no = u.chassis_no;
                updateTruck.driver_name = u.driver_name;
                updateTruck.driver_no = u.driver_no;
                updateTruck.is_updated = DateTime.Now;
                updateTruck.current_run = u.current_run;
                updateTruck.last_run = lastrun;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much!! sorry for being a newbie, very little and obvious mistake of mine